# Tensorflow: `batch_size` or `steps` is required for `Tensor` or `NumPy` input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Consider the following TensorFlow code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

mnist_dataset, mnist_info = tfds.load(name = 'mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

mnist_train, mnist_test = mnist_dataset['train'], mnist_dataset['test']

num_validation_samples = 0.1 * mnist_info.splits['train'].num_examples
num_validation_samples = tf.cast(num_validation_samples, tf.int64)

num_test_samples = mnist_info.splits['test'].num_examples
num_test_samples = tf.cast(num_test_samples, tf.int64)

def scale(image, label):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image /= 255.
    return image, label

scaled_train_and_validation_data = mnist_train.map(scale)
test_data = mnist_test.map(scale)

BUFFER_SIZE = 10_000

shuffled_train_and_validation_data = scaled_train_and_validation_data.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)

validation_data = shuffled_train_and_validation_data.take(num_validation_samples)
train_data = shuffled_train_and_validation_data.skip(num_validation_samples)

BATCH_SIZE = 100
train_data = train_data.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
validation_data = validation_data.batch(num_validation_samples) # Single batch, having size equal to number of validation samples
test_data = test_data.batch(num_test_samples)

validation_inputs, validation_targets = next(iter(validation_data))

input_size = 784 # One for each pixel of the 28 * 28 image
output_size = 10
hidden_layer_size = 50 # Arbitrary chosen

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28,1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'), # First hidden layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
NUM_EPOCHS = 5
model.fit(train_data, epochs = NUM_EPOCHS, validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets), verbose=2)
```

On running it tf gives the error:

> ValueError: `batch_size` or `steps` is required for `Tensor` or
>   `NumPy` input data.

When batch_size is added in the call to `fit()`:

```
model.fit(train_data, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, epochs = NUM_EPOCHS, validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets), verbose=2)
```

It then complains:

> ValueError: The `batch_size` argument must not be specified for the
>   given input type. Received input: , batch_size: 100

What is the error here?

Comment: Do you copy the full codes to here? I saw `BUFFER_SIZE=10_000`, `model.compile(optimize=...)` these typos. Please exactly copy and paste the code that caused the bug you showed.

Comment: @zihaozhihao Why do you think that is a typo? I've extracted code snippets out of a Jupyter notebook. I left out the markdown as that would make it too verbose.

Comment: it should be optimizer and 10000

Comment: @zihaozhihao Underscores are supported in numbers. See `PEP 515`. Good catch on the optimizer though. The code works because`compile()` takes multiple args using `**kwargs`. It ignores the misspelled variable and continues with the default optimizer. Fixed that. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error happens because a [tf.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) is provided to the argument `validation_data` of [Model.fit](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit), but Keras does not know how many steps to validate for. To solve this problem, you can just set the argument `validation_steps`. For example:

```
model.fit(train_data,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
    validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets),
    validation_steps=10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm a bit hesitant about asking such basic questions on SO. But I'm a Java developer and both Python and Tf are very new to me.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think there is anything wrong with asking - many other people might benefit from your questions. Always happy to help!

Comment: @rvinas thank you for including a little bit explanation how the code will solve the issue. It really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
NUM_EPOCHS=5
    model.fit(train_data,epochs= NUM_EPOCHS,
    validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets),
    validation_steps=10,verbose=2)
```

Comment: You don't need the batch_size argument here as you have already specified BATCH_SIZE = 100
train_data = train_data.batch(BATCH_SIZE) before.

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: How do I know how many validation steps are required?

Answer (score 1):

If you visit this link - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model, you will find that fit() requires the argument - validation_steps only if validation_data is provided and is a tf.data dataset. As in your code, it looks like you created the validation_data by splitting the training part of dataset.